# specific colours are required within Hexbin package?

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting scatter plot for high density of dots.I used Hexbin package and I successfully plot the data.The colour is not pretty,and I am asked to follow a standard  colour. I wonder if it is supported by R. Image shows my out put(right) and the wanted colour(left).[image]

Example:

```
    x <- rnorm(1000)
    y <- rnorm(1000)
   bin<-hexbin(x,y, xbins=50) 
   plot(bin, main="Hexagonal Binning")
```

Comment: +1 for making a *small reproducible example*!! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the example on the package helpapge for `hexbin` you can get close using `rainbow` and playing with the `colcuts` argument like so...

```
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)
(bin <- hexbin(x, y))

plot(hexbin(x, y + x*(x+1)/4),main = "Example" ,
     colorcut = seq(0,1,length.out=64),
     colramp = function(n) rev(rainbow(64)),
     legend = 0 )
```

[image]

You will need to play with the legend specification etc to get exactly what you want.

Alternative colour palette suggested by [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)

```
## nicer colour palette
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("darkorchid4","darkblue","green","yellow", "red") )
plot(hexbin(x, y + x*(x+1)/4), main = "Example" ,
colorcut = seq(0,1,length.out=24),
colramp = function(n) cols(24) ,
legend = 0 )
```

[image]

Comment: @ZadSim Because I set `legend = 0` to make the plot clearer. Just remove that argument in the `plot` command.

Comment: Something like `colramp = colorRampPalette(c("darkorchid4","darkblue","green","yellow", "red"))` should look nicer.

Comment: Yes I agree (I'd never use `rainbow` in practice!), and I was going to look up some hex colours for that very purpose, but I figured I should leave something for the OP to do. I will update with that colour palette though since you did the leg work! :-)