# how to add marks and change colors along with points in the hexbin plot

Tags: r

I used hexbin to generate the following plot. The code is as follows:

```
plot(hexbin(fit[,1],fit[,2]))
```

[image]

The current color is gray. Is that possible to change the color of points? In addition, are there any approaches to allow me add some identifications along with the points on the plot. Currently, each point on the plot may correspond to multiple data points. Can I mark each point with its pair of (x-value, y-value)? Thanks.

The data set of fit is like this

```
           ID           V1  V2
           1    -9.2523712  1.751943612
           2    -0.9799493  0.067998776
           3    -0.9799493  0.067998776
           4    3.2156859   1.088934239
           5    3.4915597   1.097911743
           6    3.4915597   1.097911743
           7    -0.9799493  0.067998776
           8    -0.9799493  0.067998776
           9    -0.9799493  0.067998776
          10    3.2156859   1.088934239
          11    3.2156859   1.088934239
          12    -13.8501443 -5.890093824
          13    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          14    -0.9640125  -14.95128161
          15    -0.9658289  -13.24860424
          16    -0.9640125  -14.95128161
          17    3.2156859   1.088934239
          18    4.712371    -1.967570575
          19    2.6971679   -0.376915822
          20    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          21    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          22    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          23    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          24    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          25    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          26    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          27    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          28    -9.2523712  1.751943612
          29    -9.2523712  1.751943612
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at grid.hexagons, i.e.,

```
?grid.hexagons
```

in R.  The help page gives some good examples of how to play around with the color functions.  Also, this question has been more or less answered before:

[specific colours are required within Hexbin package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573871/specific-colours-are-required-within-hexbin-package)

so hopefully that helps you out.  I wasn't able to figure out how to add the text to the plot yet though.